# Detecting modules that get imported on condition

Tags: python, abstract-syntax-tree

I need to extract names of modules that are imported in a `mypy`-typed file, such as:

```
from typing import TYPE_CHECKING
if TYPE_CHECKING:
    import abc
    from django.utils import timezone
```

Based on the example above, the "name-extractor" function should return `django.utils.timezone` and `abc`, but it should not return `typing.TYPE_CHECKING`.

The only way, and a super-hacky and magical one I could come up with is using the `ast` and `compile` libraries:

```
import ast

code = """
from typing import TYPE_CHECKING
if TYPE_CHECKING:
    import abc
    from django.utils import timezone

if 'aaa':
    print('bbb')

print('hello world')
"""
tree = ast.parse(code)

# removing all nodes except for "if TYPE_CHECKING"
tree.body = [
    b for b in tree.body
    if isinstance(b, ast.If)
       and isinstance(b.test, ast.Name)
       and b.test.id == 'TYPE_CHECKING'
]

compiled = compile(tree, filename="<ast>", mode="exec")
print(compiled.co_names)
```

Is there a proper way to do this?

Comment: why are you importing unused modules?

Comment: @AzatIbrakov what makes you think they are unused?

Comment: in your code snippet you are not using them, that's all

Comment: btw your check doesn't handle cases when there is a module object called `TYPE_CHECKING` also if there is a case with absolute import like `import typing ... if typing.TYPE_CHECKING: ...`

Comment: @AzatIbrakov well, let's suppose I use these modules down the road, I just did not put the in the example to reduce visual noise :)

Comment: @AzatIbrakov and yes, my check does not handle a lot of cases, I really need a better one

Answer (score 0):

Your original approach with `ast` is a good start, but you may end up in missing some of edge-cases (like the ones I've already mentioned in comments), it's a lot of work that can be avoided.

If you don't mind importing module you are analyzing (and we are sure that all of submodules like `django` are present) then we can do this in a "dirty" way:

1. Import module with `TYPE_CHECKING` set to `False` (default).
2. Import module with `TYPE_CHECKING` set to `True`.
3. Compare 2 modules and get "extra" submodules names.

First of all let's define utility function for monkey patching

```
from contextlib import contextmanager


@contextmanager
def patch(object_, attribute_name, value):
    old_value = getattr(object_, attribute_name)
    try:
        setattr(object_, attribute_name, value)
        yield
    finally:
        setattr(object_, attribute_name, old_value)
```

after that our function can be written using `importlib` module (for dynamic imports & reloading) and `inspect` module (for checking if object is a module) from stdlib like

```
import importlib
import inspect
import typing


def detect_type_checking_mode_modules_names(module_name):
    module = importlib.import_module(module_name)
    default_module_names = set(vars(module))

    with patch(typing, 'TYPE_CHECKING', True):
        # reloading since ``importlib.import_module``
        # will return previously cached entry
        importlib.reload(module)
    type_checked_module_namespace = dict(vars(module))

    # resetting to "default" mode
    importlib.reload(module)

    return {name
            for name, content in type_checked_module_namespace.items()
            if name not in default_module_names
            and inspect.ismodule(content)}
```

## Test

For a `test.py` module with contents

```
from typing import TYPE_CHECKING

if TYPE_CHECKING:
    import abc
    from django.utils import timezone

if 'aaa':
    print('bbb')

print('hello world')
```

gives us

```
>>> detect_type_checking_mode_modules_names('test')
{'abc', 'timezone'}
```